# unable to set optional language in url in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

i am facing problem while routing URL of web in MVC3. i override function as

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapPageRoute("GrpViewRoute", "Report/{ReportName}", "~/Views/Offer/{ReportName}.aspx");
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters

            new { language = "en",  controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        //routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
    }
```

This is working fine if i request as "language/home/index" i need to provide language every time. is there any solution that I i can access site as "home/index". If i not provide language by default it en.

Comment: Why do you need this? Seems like strange requirement.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters

            new { language = "en",  controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

put this after your current map route.